# How to get a char sequence from String that contains a searched string

Tags: java, string, char, contains

I would like to know if their is a function in JAVA that allows to retrieve from a huge string a char sequence that contains a special char.

Example: I have a php page that that I've stringified and I check if there is a char sequence containing the char "@". If it's the case, I would like to get just the whole char sequence that contains the searched char.

I can use String.contains("@") to look for the char but how to get the char which contains it ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: What do you mean by "a char sequence that contains the char"? The whole string is a char sequence that contains it. So which char sequence do you mean?

Comment: Imagine, "mailto = test@mail.com" is the whole string. I've got to know that the string contains the searched char "@" but now how to retrieve "test@mail.com"...

Comment: You should be able to define a set of characters preceding and/or following `@` to delimit the surrounding substring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a regular expression based on

"mailto = (test@mail.com)"

If this is found in the stringified php, you can conveniently extract the parenthesized section.

But most likely it could be `foo@bar.com` as well, and so you may have to write a more complicated regular expression, but it'll work the same way.

Here's a version matching any valid email address:

```
"mailto = ([A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+(?:\\.[A-Za-z]){1,3}\\b)"
```

Perhaps the spaces before and after `=` aren't guaranteed, so you might make them optional:

```
"mailto ?= ?(...)"
```

To execute the match, use

```
Pattern pat = Pattern.compile( "mailto = ([A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+(?:\\.[A-Za-z]){1,3}\\b)" );
```

and, with the php in a String you can then do

```
String php = ...;
Matcher mat = pat.matcher( php );
if( mat.find() ){
    String email = mat.group( 1 );
}
```

The find can be called repeatedly to find all occurrences.

See [another SO Q+A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/using-a-regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-address) for the discussion of a regular expression matching an email address.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your contribution :)

Comment: I just noticed that the pattern I grabbed from somewhere was missing a parentheses to combine the repeated ".xxx" in the second part. fixed.

Comment: And please note that other SO Q+A I added to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Since the regex idea was already taken, here's another approach

```
String test = "abc 123 456@789 abcde";
String charToFind = "@";

String strings[] = test.split(" ");
for( String str : strings ){
  if( str.contains(charToFind) ){ System.out.println(str); }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a combination of [indexOf](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(java.lang.String)) and [substring](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int)) to find and extract the substring.

Without more info on how the source and the searched string look like it's hard to help you further.

Comment: Please don't write comments as answers.

Comment: @laune I thought this one was on the line, but I appreciate your feedback

Comment: If you'd have backed it up with a snippet of code, I'd agree with you.

Comment: Fair enough, I'll keep it in mind for next time I'm in a similar situation. :)